# Abstract class member can't access value set in derived classes

Tags: c++, g++

I have the following abstract class

```
class Language {
    const std::string name ;

    protected:
    std::string cmd, home ;
    Config::Section cfg ;

    bool load_conf() {
        home = env("HOME") ;

        // DEBUG
        std::cout << home << std::endl ;
        std::cout << name << std::endl ;

        if (!cfg.load(home + "/.cr", name)) {
            std::cerr << "cr: No configuration found for this language." << std::endl ;
            return false ;
        }

        return true ;
    }

    public:        
    virtual bool handles(const std::string) = 0 ;
    virtual int run(std::string) = 0 ;
} ;
```

And a number of derived classes, like this, which implement it

```
class Python : public Language {
    const std::string name ;

    public:
    Python() : name("python") {}

    bool handles(const std::string) ;
    int run(std::string) ;
};
```

The problem I'm having is in `load_conf()` where for some reason `name` is reported to be empty, which makes it spit out an error even though the configuration is fine. `load_conf()` is called from `run()` which is implemented by each derived class.

I've tried making `name` protected and public, but neither seems to make any difference. Ideally I'd like to only declare `name` in the abstract class (as protected) and not have to repeat the declaration in each derived class, but when I try that it won't compile. I've also tried using `this->name` but that's also empty, and removing the `const` also makes no difference.

I get the feeling it's a scoping issue, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare a constructor in your base class which accepts a single argument, the value to intialize `name` to and pass that in the derived ctors.

here is an example:

```
class Language {
    const std::string name ;
};

class Python : public Language {
    const std::string name ; // <-- this is different, and frankly redundant
};
```

Something like the following should replace the above...

```
class Language {
    const std::string name ;
    Language(std::string some_name) : name(some_name) {}  // <-- set the name
};

class Python : public Language {
    Python() : Language("python") {} // construct the base with the name...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a variable with named `name` in the Base class `Language` When you refer to `name` inside `load_conf()` the compiler refers to the Base class `name` variable and not derived class `name` variable.

Simple solution is to have separate names for the two variables or
Make the `name` in Base class as `protected` so each derived class can refer to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

in your `class Python`you are overriding the field `name` which is not the one referenced by `load_conf`.

Make `name` in your `Language` class `protected` and remove the one in its subclasses and it should work well.